# run makefile generated by eclipse from command line after updating code not working

Tags: c++, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm running

> eclipse juno Service Release 2 Build id: 20130225-0426 with [this CDT config](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1414360/CDTconfig.png)

and this OS:

(truncated output of `uname -a`): `Linux 3.2.0-51-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I create a HelloWorld C++ project as follows:

- File->New->C++ Project
- Project type: Executable Empty Project
- Toolchains: Cross GCC
- Configurations: Debug and Release checked

Then I create a C++ source file `Main.cpp` that contains hello world code.

I can then compile using the hammer icon. I choose to compile in Release mode. The program runs fine (inside eclipse or at the command line) and prints "hello".
If I modify the code to print out "hello there", I can recompile with the hammer and the program still runs fine and prints out "hello there".

However, if I modify the code to print out "hello there you", go to the Release directory (`/home/user/workspace/HelloWorld/Release`) and type make, I get this message: `make: Nothing to be done for 'Main.d'`.

There is a file called makefile in the Release directory, but it's not behaving like a normal makefile. I would expect this makefile to be such that when there is a change in the code and you type make, the code gets actually recompiled. If I type `make clean` followed by `make`, the code gets recompiled but this is inefficient for larger projects.

Do you know why the makefile generated by eclipse is behaving this way ? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try 
**$make all**, instead of **$make** it should work.